# No Tests were executed

Tags: jersey-test-framework

I am new to Jersy framework and when I run a test case using Jersey Framework to test RESTful web-services I am getting an error as "No tests executed".

The test looks as below

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.test.framework.AppDescriptor;
import com.sun.jersey.test.framework.JerseyTest;
import com.sun.jersey.test.framework.WebAppDescriptor;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import javax.json.JsonException;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import junit.framework.Assert;
import static junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class UserServiceTestJersy extends JerseyTest {

    public UserServiceTestJersy() {
    }


    @Override
    protected AppDescriptor configure(){
        return new WebAppDescriptor.Builder().build();
    }


    @Test
    public void testUserFetchesSuccess() throws JsonException, URISyntaxException{
        WebResource webResource=client().resource("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/");
        JsonObject json=webResource.path("posts/2").get(JsonObject.class);

       assertEquals("1",json.get("userId"));
       assertEquals("1",json.get("id"));


    }
}
```

I can't sort out the error. I want to test a RESTful web service. But I am getting exceptions as follows,

```
Running UserServiceTestJersy

org.apache.maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)

Caused by: org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot instantiate class UserServiceTestJersy
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:38)


org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:522)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:157)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1299)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1286)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:70)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:109)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:111)
    ... 9 more

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:29)
    ... 28 more

Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.uri(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder;
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:119)
    at com.sun.jersey.test.framework.JerseyTest.getBaseURI(JerseyTest.java:496)
    at com.sun.jersey.test.framework.JerseyTest.getContainer(JerseyTest.java:342)
    at com.sun.jersey.test.framework.JerseyTest.<init>(JerseyTest.java:165)
    at UserServiceTestJersy.<init>(UserServiceTestJersy.java:28)
    ... 33 more



Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is my POM file

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.19.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-external</artifactId>
  <version>1.19.1</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Maybe you could also describe what you are trying to accomplish with your code.

Comment: Are you running `mvn test`? Without extra configuration, I think there is a naming convention you must follow for your test classes. Try changing the name of the test class to `UserServiceTest`

Comment: `java.lang.AbstractMethodError` - Looks like some dependency version incompatibilities. Also you should keep in mind that `JerseyTest` is for JUnit. I don't know if there is TestNg support in Jersey 1.x. I looked through [the repo](https://github.com/jersey/jersey-1.x/tree/master/jersey-test-framework) and can't find anything. I know Jersey 2.x support TestNg, but it doesn't look like you are using 2.x

Comment: Unless TestNg (which I don't use) also supports JUnit `@Before` and `@After` annotations, then your tests won't start up the server correctly. So once you fix the dependency version issue, then you need to switch to JUnit

Comment: Thanx . Changing the name of the test class didn't work for me. I am using Jersey 1.19.1.

Comment: Make sure all the version of all your Jersey dependencies are the same, and remove any unnecessary jax-rs or jsr311 dependencies. They will get pulled in by jersey.

Comment: I haven't used any jax-rs or jsr311 dependencies.

Comment: Remove the javaee, that comes with jax-rs 2. If you are using Java ee 7 for your application, then you should be using Jersey 2, which uses jax-rs 2. Java ee 6 uses Jax-rs 1, which is what jersey 1 uses